# Windows firewall advanced security & mail

Tags: windows, windows-firewall

How do you allow Windows Mail through Windows firewall with advanced security? I have included in exception lists, both in and out, winmail.exe and ports 25 and 110. But Windows Mail still only works if I allow all outbound traffic.

Answer (score 1):

It's not the email client that dictates which ports on the email server are used for client connections, it's the email server. Which ports does your email provider use for incoming client connections for POP, IMAP, and SMTP? Those are the ports you need to allow outbound in the Windows firewall.

Answer (score 0):

A lot of Windows mail clients use port 587 outbound.  You might try enabling that port as well.  If that doesn't work, I'd check the logs for Windows Firewall, and/or run a packet tracing tool like Wireshark (with the firewall turned off) to see what ports winmail is actually trying to get to.